# How do I download MatLab packages?

Tags: matlab, package

It seems this has not been asked before - and maybe I'm too dumb to figure it out myself. I am trying to download a specific MatLab package and being decently new to MatLab - I have no idea how to get it to work. There is no exe file or anything that denotes usefulness in "downloading" it into my MatLab software. The package in question can be found [[here]](http://metaopen.sourceforge.net/metsign.html). It is called MetSign - open-source made by UL and I would like to check it out. Thank you for any help.

Comment: As often happens with academic software, there's no directions for installation or use. That means you're on your own. Or you can try prodding the authors to see if they're willing to complete their software by adding documentation. Don't hold your breath... :/

Comment: That said, if it's just a collection of M-files, download them to any directory on your local drive, then add that directory to your MATLAB path using the function `addpath`.

Answer (score 1):

On the link you provide, at the bottom there's a link saying "download". Click that, and it will take you to SourceForge, a download website for open source software. Wait for a few seconds, and download of a `.zip` file will start. Wait for the download to complete, and save the `.zip` file somewhere on your computer. Unzip the file to somewhere on your computer. Inside you'll find a bunch of `.m` files. These are MATLAB code files. Within MATLAB, add the folder containing the downloaded code to your MATLAB path using the command `addpath`. Now run the code. I can't help you much with that step, as I have no idea what the code does, but on the original download page there are also links to some academic papers describing the code - I imagine these will give you some hints about how to run it.